# How to replace a component with another one upon event (button click) in react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a long list of data display divided into blocks with an edit button on side of each block, like this:
[image]

Whenever the edit button is clicked, i need to replace the display component with edit component, replacing the text with form like this

[image]

what would be the best way to do this.
I have tried putting the components inside state as list and replacing Display component with Form Component, when Edit is clicked
so instead of returning this from render():

```
return(
 <Display />
 );
```

Now i am returning:

```
return(
 {this.state.components[0]}
  );
```

and when button is clicked doing this

```
this.setState({components:[<EditForm />]})
```

It works but i was wondering is storing Component and JSX inside state a good idea/ professional practice?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. Do you have a reason to use this instead of if/else or maybe an object to store the components ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you could do something like this:
`use a variable in state for knowing edit is clicked or not`

```
state={
   isEdit:false,
  }
```

`on click of edit:` 
          `this.setState({isEdit:true})`

`in render() use conditional rendering:`

```
render(){
   return(
    <div>
        {(!this.state.isEdit) ? <Display /> : <EditForm />}
     </div>
       )
     }
```

Comment: @yogesh if my answer worked accept it so that it will hel others too

Comment: aravind_reddy how to pass data in EditForm component?

Comment: you can pass down as props like: `<EditForm  data={data} />`

Comment: Can you give/tell what you have tried ? Maybe put in sandbox or something so that it is easy to help

Comment: What if you want the history to be updated so the back button of the browser redirects to the previous component?

Comment: @Andre thats a different scenario altogether if you can post a new question with your code.. will be happy to help

Comment: @aravind_reddy I got it. Just defined `BrowserRouter` and my routes in the parent `<App/>` component then used `this.match.history.push('/path')` inside a child component.

Answer (score 0):

I would hold in state just a Boolean for showing the edit form or the display and toggle this on button click.

Then in you render method just a simple if statement to choose what to render e.g.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.edit) return <EditForm />
    return <Display />
}
```